# Как сохранить картинку на сервере по ее URL?

Tags: php

Есть адрес картинки, например http://site.com/images/image.jpg. Как, имея в переменной адрес этой картинки, сохранить ее на сервере в созданной папке?

Comment: `file_put_contents` + `file_get_contents` / `copy`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url